# How to delete all files that contains " (2)" wildcards dont work

Tags: rm, wildcards

I would like to delete all files that contains " (2)" --whitout the quotes-- in the file names. I tried first with ls to test

```
ls *(2)*
```

and list all the files in the folder

```
ls "*(2)*"
```

don't list any file, how I have to format the wildcard to do the right thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape (or quote) the parentheses - but not the glob wildcards `*` e.g.

```
ls *\(2\)*
```

or

```
ls *"(2)"*
```

or even

```
ls *'('2')'*
```

If you want to match the leading space explicitly, you will need to escape or quote that as well e.g.

```
ls *\ \(2\)*
```

or

```
ls *' (2)'*
```