# Syntax error while deleting files with `(` character in the name

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to delete a file using the console with this command

```
rm ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(1).deb
```

but I get a syntax error. What is wrong with this command?

Comment: You need to quote or escape the special characters - see related [How to delete all files that contains “ (2)” wildcards dont work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694262/how-to-delete-all-files-that-contains-2-wildcards-dont-work)

Comment: ... also [How do I enter a file or directory with special characters in its name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101587/how-do-i-enter-a-file-or-directory-with-special-characters-in-its-name)

Comment: You can <tab> after the first few characters of a filename and the terminal will fill in as required. So `rm google-c<TAB>` will probably fill in the name as the terminal expects it.

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? Show us the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses are treated specially by the shell. [Quote them](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) to remove their special meaning so the shell treats them literally.

There are three major forms of quoting, and for this purpose any of them will do:

- Since `(` and `)` are not the `'` character, they're treated literally inside [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) (so long as the single quotes are not themselves quoted).
- Since they are not `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, or `!`, they're treated literally inside [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) (so long as the double quotes are not themselves quoted).
- Like any character, they're treated literally [after a `\`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) (so long as the backslash is not itself quoted).

Thus any of the following will work:

```bsh
rm ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64\(1\).deb  # backslashes
```

```bsh
rm './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(1).deb'  # single quotes
```

```bsh
rm "./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(1).deb"  # double quotes
```

Though less commonly done, you can also use single quotes or double quotes to quote less than the full argument. For example, these also work:

```bsh
rm ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64'(1)'.deb
```

```bsh
rm ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64"(1)".deb
```

As a separate matter, note that you don't need the leading `./` in the path here, though it's fine to include it. With `rm`, you'd only need it if the path started with a `-` character, which `rm` would attempt to treat as one or more options rather than a path. (Though you could alternatively pass a separate `--` argument before the path to indicate that all separate arguments are paths and not options.)