# Error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: command-line

i am trying to run vmware player an i get an error:bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
this is the command i was using:

```
chmod a+x VMware-Player-16.0.0-16894299.x86_64 (1).bundle
```

i have also tryed this:

```
sudo VMware-Player-16.0.0-16894299.x86_64 (1).bundle
```

i am running linux mint 19,3

Comment: Welcome! Only Ubuntu-related questions are answered here and considered on-topic. Any other OS is considered off-topic. You could still use the search button and find questions and answers that might also help, although not guaranteed.

Comment: Overall I can suggest: Have you tried using quotes ( " ) on such complex names?

Comment: It's essentially a dupe of [Syntax error while deleting files with `(` character in the name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260395/syntax-error-while-deleting-files-with-character-in-the-name) anyhow

Comment: I agree with @steeldriver - this has been answered frequently. The one tip I found 'missing' the this one about [TAB completion](https://askubuntu.com/a/101602/1127942) (you'll have to click through 4 duplicates - that's why I mention it again).

Answer (score 1):

Use some quotes, because without them this is like you are giving another argument to chmod.

```
sudo chmod a+x "VMware-Player-16.0.0-16894299.x86_64 (1).bundle"
```